# SQL nested aggregate function as subquery syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, average, derived

I need to perform an average of averages. Figured out how to write the subquery, but the final function throws two errors. Syntax error on line 15 and then on line 1.

The subquery works. I then just need an average of the averages of the products in the same category. What's missing?

```
SELECT
   c."name",
   AVG(avgvalue)
FROM
   (SELECT
       c.name, 
       p.name,
       AVG(a."value") AS avgvalue
   FROM 
       answers a 
   INNER JOIN 
       survey_responses sr ON sr.id = a.survey_response_id 
                           AND a.question_id = 13
   INNER JOIN 
       answers category_answer ON category_answer.survey_response_id = sr.id 
                               AND category_answer.question_id = 264
   INNER JOIN 
       answers_categories ac ON category_answer.id = ac.answer_id
   INNER JOIN 
       categories c ON c.id = ac.category_id
   INNER JOIN 
       products p ON p.id = a.product_id
   WHERE 
       c.name IN ('Accounting') 
   HAVING 
       count(p.name) > 10) AS ProductAverages
GROUP BY c.NAME
```

Comment: Your RDBMS is – _[tag it in the question]_?

Comment: ";" terminates the statement

Comment: You're also missing a `group by`

Comment: That was silly of me. I added and updated query, now I'm getting a syntax error on line 3

Answer (score 1):

Remove `;` after the `HAVING` clause in the temporary table

```
HAVING count(p.name)>10
```